# How to write a Jest/Vitest unit test for an array filter method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, vitest

I am new to React and learning Automated testing for the first time.
I have a very simple application, which essentially uses Dummy Data, and renders a table based on the data.

I also have a search input the user can use to filter the data.

I am trying to write a unit test for my function that filters the array based on the search input and then return the filtered array that is set in State.

My function is as follows,

```
const onClickHandler = () => {
    // Filter state data
    const filteredData = originalData.filter((entity) =>
      entity.entityType.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchInput)
    );
    setFilterData(filteredData);
  };
```

I am struggling to understand how I would write a unit test that covers this logic.

I have been able to write a test that covers the search input and the resetting of the input if the user clicks a Reset button.

Apologies, I hope I have explained this well enough.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define what is a unit in your code, and the extract you pasted misses a lot of contexts.

I will assume:

- the unit is a function
- that function is "importable/visible" from the test scope (I'm missing the `export` in `export const onClickHandler = ...`)
- `originalData` and `searchInput` are the parameters

So:

```js
// file...
export const onClickHandler = (originalData, searchInput) => {
  const filteredData = originalData.filter(({ entityType }) => (
    entityType.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchInput))
  );
  setFilterData(filteredData);
};
```

For any test, I like the `AAA` approach:

```js
// test...
import { onClickHandler } from 'path/to/file';

describe('path/to/file/and/file/name.ts', () => {

  it('should filter values be searchInput', () => {
    // ARRANGE
    const searchInput = 'fo';
    const originalData = [{ entityType: 'FOO' }, { entityType: 'BAR' }]
    // ACT
    const result = onClickHandler(originalData, searchInput);
    // ASSERT
    expect([result]).toEqual(originalData[0]);
  }

};
```

If the function `setFilterData` is defined outside the tested unit, I use a mock instead of the original.

I hope that helps!
Cheers